# Limit with integral, case infinity * 0

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I attached an image with a limit, how can I solve that limit? If I use mean value theorem for integral it will be indeterminate form infinity * zero.[image]

Comment: What are $t$ and $g$?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Even the colours can be done in MathJax! Try inserting the following into your question: `$$\int_{\color{cyan}{a}}^{\color{purple}{b}} f(x) dx = f(\color{red}{c})(\color{purple}{b} - \color{cyan}{a})$$`

Comment: @theo in some countries tg is the shorthand for tangent instead of tan

Comment: @NinadMunshi Handy! I didn't know that one.

Comment: OP substitute $u = \tan^{n+1}x$ then move the limit into the integral.

Comment: @TheoBendit thank you for suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $u=\tan^{n+1}x \implies \frac{du}{1+u^{\frac{2}{n+1}}} = (n+1)\tan^nxdx$

$$\frac{n}{n+1}\int_0^1\frac{du}{1+u^{\frac{2}{n+1}}} \longrightarrow  \int_0^1\frac{du}{1+1} = \frac{1}{2}$$